# How can I document ZF1 helper to get an autocomplete in my IDE

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpstorm, phpdoc

I'm working with ZF1 and we have helpers in the project. By default IDE doesn't understand which class will be returned in that expression:

```
$this->getHelper('CRM')->getModeDependantLink($url);
```

So the system doesn't what will be returned by `$this->getHelper('CRM')` and can't find the method `getModeDependantLink()`

I can write this code in two lines to achieve the goal:

```
/** @var Lead_Helper_CRM $helperCRM */
$helperCRM = $this->getHelper('CRM');
$helperCRM->getModeDependantLink($url);
```

The PHPDoc explains to the IDE that `$this->getHelper('CRM')` returns object of `Lead_Helper_CRM` and then IDE knows everything about method `getModeDependantLink()`

But I don't like 2 lines of code. I'd like to get the same, but for one line code, something like:

```
/** @class Lead_Helper_CRM $this->getHelper('CRM') */
$this->getHelper('CRM')->getModeDependantLink($url);
```

Could please someone tell me if it possible to do with some PHPDoc trick? If yes, could you please show me a simple rough example how it can be done?

Comment: One possible solution: Advanced Metadata -- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata

Comment: `/** @class Lead_Helper_CRM $this->getHelper('CRM') */` --- this will not work 1) as you can typehint this way only top level entity (variable) 2) you are trying to typehint 2.1) a method call and 2.2) with specific parameter... -- nope

Comment: You may try and do what ashnazg is suggesting (typehint `getHelper()` in actual class and list all possible return types) .. but that long/inconvenient and not even possible in some cases. P.S. In regards to my 2nd comment -- I thought you were using `@var` tag. There is no `@class` tag that PHPDoc or PhpStorm would support. This whole idea is wrong (not supported by IDE or PHPDoc logic in general).

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility *might* be the `@return` tag on the `getHelper()` method.

*If* it lists all possible returned classes,

and *if* your IDE knows how to interpret that

(and thus shows all potential methods from all those potential classes)...

That is the only scenario where what you want (method popup against the `getHelper()->`) *might* work.